# I want to display data according to product p_id

Tags: php, mysql

My 3 tables namely product, band, product Info

Product

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `product` (
  `p_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `product` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`p_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=3 ;
INSERT INTO `product` (`p_id`, `product`) VALUES
(1, 'Atta'),
(2, 'OIl');
```

Brand

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `brand` (
  `b_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `p_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `brand` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `image` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`b_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=4 ;
```

Insert

```
INSERT INTO `brand` (`b_id`, `p_id`, `brand`, `image`) VALUES
(1, 1, 'Ashirvad', 'FreeVector-Blue-Squares-Vector.jpg'),
(2, 1, 'Phillsberry', 'ILBAGNOALESSI_One_02.jpg'),
(3, 2, 'Sunflower', '001-bi-fold-corporate-brochure-template-vol-1-2.jpg');
```

Product Info

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `product_info` (
  `pi_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `pro` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `b_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `quantity` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  `measurement` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  `mrp` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  `our_price` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`pi_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=4 ;
```

Insert

```
INSERT INTO `product_info` (`pi_id`, `pro`, `b_id`, `quantity`, `measurement`, `mrp`, `our_price`) VALUES
(1, 1, 1, '1', 'kg', '50', '48'),
(2, 1, 2, '1', 'kg', '60', '59'),
(3, 2, 3, '1', 'ltr', '90', '86');
```

When i use the below query to display data according to the p_id, it displays data correctly

```
<?php
                // Make a MySQL Connection
                $con = mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "");
                  if (!$con)
                {
                  die('Could not Connect to DB :'. mysql_error());
                }
                mysql_select_db("mr_bazaar",$con);

                $result = mysql_query("select * FROM product"); 
                echo '<ul class="list-1 p2">'; 
                while($row = mysql_fetch_array( $result )) {
                    // Print out the contents of each row into a table

                    echo '<li>';
                    echo "<a href='page1.php?$row[p_id]'>";
                    echo '<b>';
                    echo $row['product'];
                    echo '</b>';
                    echo "</a>";
                    echo '</li>';
                } 
                echo '</ul>';
                mysql_close($con);
            ?>
```

and I want to display data according to the p_id in another page page1.php using the table product, brand, product_info(product from product table),(brand from brand table), (quantity, mrp from product_info table)

Answer (score 0):

Send the product id to the next page as a URL parameter. So change,

```
 echo "<a href='page1.php?$row[p_id]'>";
```

to

```
echo "<a href='page1.php?pid=$row[p_id]'>";
```

and accept the `pid` in *page1.php* using

```
$pid=$_GET['pid'];  // getting the URL parameter
```

Now you can query to get the details corresponding to the `pid`.

```
mysql_query("SELECT p.product,b.brand,pi.quantity,pi.mrp FROM product as p INNER JOIN brand as b ON p.p_id=b.p_id
INNER JOIN product_info as pi ON pi.b_id=b.b_id WHERE p.p_id=$pid");
```

Comment: Thanks for your valuable response, but when i click the first p_id(Atta) it should redirect to the page1.php and in that page brands of Atta only has to be displayed

Comment: @Vijay..That is you have to write the query for it in that page.

Answer (score 0):

1- For sending the product id to page1.php, pass the variable correctly, change

```
echo "<a href='page1.php?$row[p_id]'>";
```

to

```
echo "<a href='page1.php?pid=$row[p_id]'>";
```

2- Get the variable on page1.php using:

```
$pid = $_GET['pid'];
```

3- Query the database for record of that product

```
$result = mysql_query("select * FROM product WHERE p_id='{$pid}'");
```

*Note:

1- I would recommend you not to use `mysql_*` function use `mysqli` or `pdo` library instead, and also escape the string while getting it from GET parameter.

2- You can use joins to fetch data from other tables corresponding to current product

Comment: Thanks a lot Mr.Syed for ur valuable response